# Mariadb Galera node will not successfully rejoin unless it picks a particular node to rejoin via

Tags: mysql, mariadb, recovery, galera

Debian 10, Maridadb 10.3.26, Galera-3 25.3.31

I have a three node cluster. The nodes are named node3, node4, and node5. Node3 gets disconnected from the cluster on occasion.

If it picks node5 to recover from I get

```
2020-11-18 19:42:08 7 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 2
2020-11-18 19:42:08 7 [Note] WSREP: GCache history reset: 57b37aa2-d111-11e8-a015-ab6cf5f3b3ea:0 -> 57b37aa2-d111-11e8-a015-ab6cf5f3b3ea:75720363
2020-11-18 19:42:08 17 [Note] WSREP: SST received: 57b37aa2-d111-11e8-a015-ab6cf5f3b3ea:75696989
2020-11-18 19:42:08 17 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_start_position set to '57b37aa2-d111-11e8-a015-ab6cf5f3b3ea:75696989'
2020-11-18 19:42:08 7 [Note] WSREP: Receiving IST: 23374 writesets, seqnos 75696989-75720363
2020-11-18 19:42:08 0 [Note] WSREP: 2.0 (node5): State transfer to 0.0 (node3) complete.
2020-11-18 19:42:08 0 [Note] WSREP: Member 2.0 (node5) synced with group.
2020-11-18 19:42:08 0 [Note] WSREP: (23249d11, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
2020-11-18 19:42:15 0 [Warning] WSREP: Protocol violation. JOIN message sender 2.0 (node5) is not in state transfer (SYNCED). Message ignored.
```

after which node3 will sit forever never changing wsrep_ready to yes.

On the other hand, if node3 picks node4 I get all the same sort of messages except

`[Warning] WSREP: Protocol violation. JOIN message sender 2.0 (node5) is not in state transfer (SYNCED). Message ignored.`

does not appear and eventually node3 wsrep_ready becomes yes and the node starts to process queries.

Any idea how I much figure out the issue?

Here is some more data.  This is an example of a successful join when it chooses node4 instead of node5:

```
2020-11-19 21:12:54 7 [Note] WSREP: State transfer required:
        Group state: 57b37aa2-d111-11e8-a015-ab6cf5f3b3ea:75815331
        Local state: 57b37aa2-d111-11e8-a015-ab6cf5f3b3ea:75696989
2020-11-19 21:12:54 7 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 9 (4, 2)
2020-11-19 21:12:54 7 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 57b37aa2-d111-11e8-a015-ab6cf5f3b3ea:75815331, view# 349: Primary, number of nodes: 3, my index: 2, protocol version 3
2020-11-19 21:12:54 7 [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.
2020-11-19 21:12:56 7 [Note] WSREP: Prepared SST request: mysqldump|10.4.44.82:3360
2020-11-19 21:12:56 7 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2020-11-19 21:12:56 7 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 75815331, protocol version: 4
2020-11-19 21:12:56 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2020-11-19 21:12:56 7 [Note] WSREP: IST receiver addr using tcp://x.y.z.a:4568
2020-11-19 21:12:56 7 [Note] WSREP: Prepared IST receiver, listening at: tcp://x.y.z.a:4568
2020-11-19 21:12:56 0 [Note] WSREP: Member 2.0 (node3) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 0.0 (node4)(SYNCED) as donor.
2020-11-19 21:12:56 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 75815331)
2020-11-19 21:12:56 7 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 0
2020-11-19 21:12:56 7 [Note] WSREP: GCache history reset: 57b37aa2-d111-11e8-a015-ab6cf5f3b3ea:0 -> 57b37aa2-d111-11e8-a015-ab6cf5f3b3ea:75815331
2020-11-19 21:12:56 0 [Note] WSREP: (fcbfdc45, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
```